Trailing stop alerts
Is there a way to have Trading View only trigger an alert after a trailing stop trade fills? The default behavior is to trigger the alert as soon as the strategy.exit is called.
This triggers an alert as soon as it's called:
strategy.exit('Exit Long', 'Long', trail_points=20, trail_offset=1, loss=500, alert_message = EXITmessage)

I'd like it to trigger on a fill.
I've tried to use:
alert(EXITmessage,alert.freq_all)
strategy.exit('Exit Long', 'Long', trail_points=20, trail_offset=1, loss=500, disable_alert = true)

but the EXITmessage doesn't replace the {{strategy.order.alert_message}} in the alert.

Try barstate.isconfirmed
if barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.exit('Exit Long', 'Long', trail_points=20, trail_offset=1, loss=500, alert_message = EXITmessage)

